# How to Approve contract to transfer tokens

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-debugging

I have two contracts, one that issues a token and gives the approval for the Marketplace contract. And the other, Marketplace, allows you to put a token for sale and sell the token.

My problem happens in the following scenario:
User A issues the token and gives permission to the Marketplace
User A puts the token up for sale through the Marketplace
User B buys the token through the Marketplace
User B puts the token for sale -> Error because the Marketplace doesn't have the approval

That's why I want to give the approval for the Marketplace in the same sales function, however, it's giving an error.

```
function buyItem(uint256 id) 
    ItemExists(id)
    IsForSale(id)
    HasTransferApproval(itemsForSale[id].tokenId)
    payable 
    external {
      require(msg.value >= itemsForSale[id].price, "Not enough funds sent");
      require(msg.sender != itemsForSale[id].seller);

      itemsForSale[id].isSold = true;
      activeItems[itemsForSale[id].tokenId] = false;
      token.safeTransferFrom(itemsForSale[id].seller, msg.sender, itemsForSale[id].tokenId);
      itemsForSale[id].seller.transfer(msg.value);
      // token.approve(address(this), itemsForSale[id].tokenId, {from: msg.sender}); // I want this line to work

      emit itemSold(id, msg.sender, itemsForSale[id].price);
    }
```

Comment: the only one who can approve is the owner of the EOA. There is new stuff about approvals however, called _Self Permit_ , which allows signed approvals. Not sure if it will work in your case but you might give it an investigation, the EIP proposal is 2612

Answer (score 2, accepted):

same as you use `approve()` to approve the spending of a particular amount tokens by a particular address (spender here).

for example :

```
approve(contract_address, amount)
```

then in contract, you can call transferFrom() method in the contracts function as shown below:

```
function sellToken() public {
    transferFrom(sender, recipient, amount)
}
```

Let me know if this works for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the token contract it should be possible to give authorization to some addresses to 'approve' tokens on behalf of the users.

OpenSea does something similar in `isApprovedForAll` from [ERC721Tradable.sol](https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-creatures/blob/master/contracts/ERC721Tradable.sol).